# Live audio streaming from IP camera/rtsp to website

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, rtsp, live-streaming, ip-camera

I have a Dahua IP camera with a microphone. I would like to get the audio stream playing on a website like a live radio.

I have a raspberry pi which I was planning to use with ffmpeg, but I haven't had much success in bridging the gap between that and my website to form an audio stream.

- Can this be done via sftp/ftp with mp3 files and some fancy php/javascript to play like a live radio?
- Do I need to use another service? (would like to minimise costs as much as possible!)

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: How many listeners do you plan to have at any particular given time?  What are your latency requirements?  Icecast is the go-to for this, but if you can't run a separate server and need to rely on a file/blob-based CDN, you can use DASH.  This will increase latency.

Comment: 10 listeners max most likely.  I will look into DASH.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can't play RTSP source directly so you need a streaming server to get the RTSP stream and convert it to something suitable for HTML5 playback (HLS/DASH).

This can be done with Wowza SE (the free developer license could be used for 10 subscribers). 
You can see how this works with the [VideoNow.Live - IP Camera Restreaming](https://videonow.live/broadcast-ip-camera-or-stream/) feature and see how this is done by taking a peek at the open source code of the [Live Streaming HTML5 RTSP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/videowhisper-live-streaming-integration/) WP plugin that powers that solution.